# not able to create react app using npx create-react-app myproject command

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

There are two issues I have faced until now: -

1.

```
Creating a new React app in E:\myproject.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
```

no progress after this command, It has been more than 1 hour running the command create-react-app

2. I uninstalled node.js and reinstalled it and run the command again but this time no src public folder is created. Also when I retried to build another app the  *issue-1* again encountered

I have applied all the solutions given in different platforms but could not fix this issue and now have no clue  how to proceed further

```
6.14.5

C:\Users\Nikki>node -v
v14.5.0
```

Comment: As a workaround , you can do one step extra: 
1. Install create-react-app separately using npm i create-react-app
2. Once done you can use create-react-app <you app name>;

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi    I tried it as well but still, the issue is not resolved

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried these command as well,

```
npm init react-app my-app
yarn create react-app my-app
```

give it try, let narrow the scope of troubleshooting

Also, Are you running behind firewall ?